# SwiftUI detect delete button pressed

Tags: swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI, but I'm coding my own custom text mask, but I need to delete when a user press the "delete" key. I'm using the `onChange` method, but it is not detecting when special keys are pressed. Currently I'm using:

```
TextField(self.placeholder, text: self.$text)
.onChange(of: self.text, perform: { value in
    print(value)
})
```

Is there a way to detect if the delete button is pressed?
Or should I use the `UITextField` instead of `TextField` ?

Comment: in which device macOS or iPhone?

Comment: You should need to use UITextField. Next should be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65840157/14733292

Comment: Answered with a full implementation example here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76684922/detect-backspace-event-on-textfield-using-subclass-or-delegate-solution-integrat/77511527#77511527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could use a hacky way for this.

- First we will hold a count of the current characters the text string has.
- Whenever the user presses backspace we check in the onChange handler if the previous character count is higher than the new character count
- if that is the case we delete the whole string, or whatever you want to do when the delete button is pressed.
- 

```
import SwiftUI
struct SquareView: View {
    
    var placeholder = "test"
    @State var text = "test"
    @State var textLen = 4
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(self.placeholder, text: self.$text)
            .onChange(of: self.text, perform: { value in
                if value.count < textLen {
                    self.text = "" // << removed the whole text but here you can insert anything you want to do when the delete button is pressed
                }
                textLen = value.count
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a hacky way and brings risks. For example if users paste something which is shorter than the current text.

Comment: .onChange is not triggered when the user presses backspace.

Answer (score 2):

**MVVM + Combine way:**

```
class RecoveryPasswordViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var email: String = ""
  @Published var isValidTextFieldStatus = true
  var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    setTextFieldToValidWhenUserDelete()
  }

  func setTextFieldToValidWhenUserDelete() {
    $email
        .scan("", { [weak self] previousInput, currentInput in
            if previousInput.count > currentInput.count {
                self?.isValidTextFieldStatus = true
            }
            return currentInput
        })
        .sink { _ in }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
 }
}
```