# Prevent user deletion in a text editor

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to prevent the user from deleting text that has been typed in a TextEditor. This is a code snippet from user AAR

I've tried to implement what I learned from doing it in a UITextField to no avail. The "textLen" would also be unnecessary for my code.

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct SquareView: View {
    
    var placeholder = "test"
    @State var text = "test"
    @State var textLen = 4
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(self.placeholder, text: self.$text)
            .onChange(of: self.text, perform: { value in
                if value.count < textLen {
                    self.text = "" // << removed the whole text but here you can insert anything you want to do when the delete button is pressed
                }
                textLen = value.count
            })
        }
    }
}
```

@ [SwiftUI detect delete button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056424/swiftui-detect-delete-button-pressed)

The user should be able to type, but not delete. I will have to figure out how to prevent Cut and Delete from the Text selector tab as well. Any Pointers are greatly apreciated as I am at a road block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a few changes to your logic to make it work.

```
var placeholder = "test"

@State var text = "test"
@State var textPrevValue = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField(self.placeholder, text: self.$text)
            .onChange(of: self.text, perform: { _ in
                if text.count < textPrevValue.count {
                    self.text = textPrevValue
                } else {
                    self.textPrevValue = self.text
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Basically what's happening here is I have a previous value that I'm setting anytime a change happens. If the count of the new value is less than the previous value, then it is inferred that there was a deletion. If the count is greater than we set a new previous value.

Comment: This works perfectly, I am not even able to cut the text either. Thank you so much.